# Class becoming an empty object while i try to access it within another class in javascript (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, circular-dependency

```js
// module1
const B = require("./module2")

module.exports = class A {
   constructor() {}

   static fun(){
      B.func().....
   }
}
```

```js
// module2
const A = require("./module1")

module.exports = class B {
   constructor(){}

   static fun(){
      A.fun()...
   }
}
```

When i console typeof class 'B' from A instead of showing function it showing type as an object
ie:-the class becoming an empty object {}
how to access class methods correctly.
It showing an error like

```js
A.fun((...) => {
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fun' of undefined
```

Comment: This looks like a cyclic dependency. A wants something form B and B wants something from A. Not sure if this will work.

Comment: @TusharShahi [Cyclic dependencies can work](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles), but you are right in that in this case, it comes with caveats.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that the two modules point to each other
try this:

```js
// A.js
import B from './B.js'
export default class A{}
```

```js
// B.js
import A from './A.js'
export default class B extends A{}
```